# How to display Bar Chart properly in AChart Engine android

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using AChart Engine to show a bar chart and want to display a bar chart like this:

[image]

But it ends up with this:
[image]

It is very frastrating and I am trying for last 4 hours to give it a proper format but failed. I searched internet for a proper tutorial but couldn't manage one. Can you please tell me what snippet should I include?

This is my trying code:

```
public class BarGraph{

    public GraphicalView getView(Context context) 
    {   
        // Bar 1

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        CategorySeries ac = new CategorySeries("AC");
        CategorySeries pe = new CategorySeries("PE");
        CategorySeries wa = new CategorySeries("WA");
        CategorySeries tl = new CategorySeries("TL");
        CategorySeries ml = new CategorySeries("ML");
        CategorySeries ce = new CategorySeries("CE");
        CategorySeries re = new CategorySeries("RE");
        CategorySeries ot = new CategorySeries("OT");
        ac.add(291);
        dataset.addSeries(ac.toXYSeries());
        pe.add(11);
        dataset.addSeries(pe.toXYSeries());
        wa.add(204);
        dataset.addSeries(ac.toXYSeries());
        tl.add(28);
        dataset.addSeries(pe.toXYSeries());
        ml.add(0);
        dataset.addSeries(ac.toXYSeries());
        ce.add(21);
        dataset.addSeries(pe.toXYSeries());
        re.add(51);
        dataset.addSeries(ac.toXYSeries());
        ot.add(4);
        dataset.addSeries(pe.toXYSeries());


        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Submission Statistics");
        mRenderer.setXTitle("Verdict Code");
        mRenderer.setYTitle("No. of Submissions");
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00AA00"));
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#666600"));
        renderer2.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer2.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer3.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        renderer3.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer3.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer4 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer4.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
        renderer4.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer4.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer5 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer5.setColor(Color.parseColor("#6767D0"));
        renderer5.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer5.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer6 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer6.setColor(Color.parseColor("#AAAA00"));
        renderer6.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer6.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer7 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer7.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00AAAA"));
        renderer7.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer7.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer8 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer8.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        renderer8.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer8.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);


        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer4);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer5);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer6);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer7);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer8);

        return ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataset,mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that instead of building `CategorySeries`, you build `XYSeries`. Then, in the first series do: `series.add(1, 291);` the second one will be `series.add(2, 11);` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, I am going to try and let you know what I get:)

Comment: After following your suggestion, the graph looks pretty good :) But I can't able to increase the bar width. I used `mRenderer.setBarSpacing(-0.5);` and it increases bar width a little. but how this negative value works?

Comment: In your case you can use mRenderer.setBarWidth(widthInPixels) because you have one item per series.

Comment: I tried to use `setBarWidth()` but it is not available to use :( I am using `achartengine-0.7.0.jar`

Comment: Ouch. Use a recent version.

Comment: I am using latest version and now it seems quite fine. Thanks! I still have some problems and I opened a new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681287/how-to-display-achartengine-bar-chart-properly . Please take a look!