# Cross-Device Compatibility Issue of AChartEngine Bar Graph

Tags: android, achartengine

I am able to develop a Bar Graph with the help of [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391554/dan) in a 7" tablet emulator and to make it fitted in this screen I used `setXAxisMax()` and `setXAxisMin()`. Here is the graph I obtained on that emulator:

[image: AChartEngine bar graph]

But when I installed it my phone with different screen, it looked like this:

**Portrait**

[image]

**Landscape**

[image]

This is my code:

```
........................
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Submission Statistics");
//      mRenderer.setXTitle("Verdict Code");
//      mRenderer.setYTitle("No. of Submissions");
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
//      mRenderer.setBarSpacing(-0.5);
//      mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
//      mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(22);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        // mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "AC");
        // mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "PE");
        // mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "WA");
        // mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "TL");
        // mRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, "ML");
        // mRenderer.addXTextLabel(6, "CE");
        // mRenderer.addXTextLabel(7, "RE");
        // mRenderer.addXTextLabel(8, "OT");
        mRenderer.setBarWidth(80);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(-6);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(15);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(311);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
            mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
........................
```

I add now `mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);` so that I can move along only x axis to see the complete chart. But user should see the full chart in screen regardless of different devices.

How to make this bar graph cross-device compatible so that it won't cut off on left and right side?

Comment: I'd be interested in this result as well, I've been using ACE quite a bit recently. One thing that I've been doing, not sure if it will help you or not, is to just get the graphical view and not the intent. This way, you get the graph and then you can drop it into a linear layout that you have holding space for it and it will automatically fit to the space allocated. I've only done this with my 10" tablet though, not sure how well it would work on a different size.

Comment: I also do it by graphical view as I am showing it in Fragment. Also I dropped it in a Linear Layout. Try yours one on different device to make sure. If it will okay, please share your code with me :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only device I have so I can't test on smaller devices. I've never used fragments so I can't really speak to those, but maybe that's the difference here. Try just setting up a test project using a simple linear layout and then add the graphical view of the bar chart programmatically in the activity to see if it works the way you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setXAxisMin()` and `setXAxisMax()` calls set the scale for the graph, not the size of the graph.

Try reducing the value passed to `setBarWidth()`. I expect that the total width of the graph is given by `num_bars * (X+Y)` where X and Y are passed to (`setBarWidth(X)` + `setBarSpacing(Y)`).

I have never built a bar chart with ACE, but I think that should be calculated based on the actual window width and the number of bars in your chart. Hope that helps.

Comment: Should I render the graph based on the device width and height calculated at runtime?

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what I am suggesting. Either that or put your chart in a scroll view so users can scroll it, but I don't think this is what you are looking for. It may also be that if you don't call setBarWidth() at all, then ACE calculates the right width for you, but I haven't tried or read the code to know if it does.